# What statistical test should be used to compare two independent sample over time (pre- and post-test) for categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures

I have baseline and follow-up surveys, asking the same 33 questions. A typical question is:

> 9. How well do you think your family knows what you are good at?
>
>    - Very Well
>    - Well
>    - Somewhat well
>    - Not at all well

I have a treatment group and a comparison group (not matched—in fact they're quite different from each other) and I'd like to statistically control for the main differences in determining if the program has had an impact.

Comment: So each person answered the questions twice? How many questions were there? Is it considered that the questions all measure the same construct?

Comment: Yes. There is a baseline survey and a follow-up, asking the same questions. There were 33 questions.

Comment: Not sure I understand the construct question. The survey addresses home and neighborhood; family and friends; how participants spend their time; and goals and action.

Comment: Are the questions intended to measure unrelated stuff, or do you have many questions that are all thought to be different ways of getting at the same idea? In essence, are you thinking of running whatever analysis 33 times (once for each question), or combining the responses into a single variable & running the analysis once on that?

Comment: Running the analysis once for each question.